# string value as name of variable

Tags: python

```
string = 's1'
result = function()
```

I want name of variable returning from function as s1 instead of result

s1 = object of some class returned from function() # that's how it should be

*****edit******

I want to make s = 10. and it is NOT answered, i have checked.

```
a = 's'

globals()['a'] = 10

print s
```

Comment: Related and/or possible duplicate: [How do I do variable variables in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1373164/953482)

Comment: See [_Why you don't want to dynamically create variables_](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/05/why-you-dont-want-to-dynamically-create.html).

Comment: Ok i figured it out... Thanks everyone!
locals()[a] = 10 is the answer